# How can I fix this Overleaf rendering issue in Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, pdf, rendering

I use Overleaf with Chrome + Microsoft Windows 10. The rendering is very poor:

[image]

How can I fix that?

I have this issue with all Overleaf projects  in Chrome + Windows 10. I don't have this issue on Chrome + Android 12:

[image]

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Resolving_access%2C_loading%2C_and_display_problems

Comment: @Gantendo thanks, [changing the PDF viewer from Overleaf to Browser](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_PDF_viewer) solved my issue.

Comment: Looks like you somehow disabled font smoothing in the browser, all fonts and font icons look bad. I very much doubt this is a supported scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Gantendo](https://superuser.com/users/1482432/gantendo)'s comment, I [changed the PDF viewer from Overleaf to Browser](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_PDF_viewer), and it solved the issue:

[image]

[image]